# Python Pyramid optional url segment

Tags: python, pyramid

I have added these routes:

```
config.add_route('api.v3.crud', 'api/v3/crud/{entity_type}')
config.add_route('api.v3.crud:id', 'api/v3/crud/{entity_type}/{id}')
```

And have these defaults and configs defined:

```
@view_defaults(route_name="api.v3.crud", permission="authenticated", renderer="json")
@view_defaults(route_name="api.v3.crud:id")
class CrudView(object):

    def __init__(self, request):
        self.request = request
        log.debug(request.method)

    @view_config(request_method='GET')
    def get(self):
        # etc...
```

I thought it was possible to define "optional" url segments this way, so that I can implement a RESTful API endpoint within the same class.  The "list" calls work (`api/v3/crud/users`), but the calls to `api/v3/crud/users/id`, for example, throws NotFound.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try using [`pviews`](https://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/narr/commandline.html#displaying-matching-views) to troubleshoot. [`proutes`](https://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/narr/commandline.html#proutes-displaying-all-application-routes) might also be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The `view_defaults` do not stack the way you probably think they do. You should only define `view_defaults` once for a class, and then it will add parameters to every `view_config` defined inside the class.